# Can the union axiom be weakened?

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC, the axiom of union is the statement that the union of any set exists. Suppose we omit this axiom, and instead add the axiom that binary unions exist. Can we still derive the full union axiom?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81815/is-the-axiom-of-union-independent-of-the-rest-of-zf) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Binary unions are a theorem of the Axiom of Replacement:

I couldn't personally find a proof of this. With choice it's relatively easy:
Assume w.l.o.g. $|A| \geq |B|$. From powerset plus specification we have a set with $2 |A|$ elements. For ease of language we'll label our two images of $A$ we've picked with $0$ and $1$. From the inclusion $B$ into $A$ (call it $f$), map $(0, a)$ to $a$, and $(1, a)$ to the unique preimage of $a$ under $f$, if it exists or $\emptyset$ otherwise. Applying axiom of replacement on our set, we get a superset of the union $A \cup B$.

I needed choice to get $|A| \leq |B|$ or $|B| \leq |A|$ for the first step.

Comment: The axiom of choice doesn't imply "$|A|\lt|B|$ or $|B|\lt|A|$". Did you mean "$|A|\le|B|$ or $|B|\le|A|$"? By the way, how do you prove "$|A|\le|B|$ or $|B|\le|A|$" using the axiom of choice? Are you sure the proof doesn't also use the axiom of union?

Comment: You're right that it should be $\leq$ not $<$. We don't need union for that proof, at least starting from well-ordering: Suppose that both A and B are well-ordered. Then build a bijection between each initial segment via transfinite induction. Transfinite induction for well-founded relations is quite weak and does not require anything more than axiom of infinity (and perhaps axiom of choice if there's a quantifier issue I'm missing).